# How to set WordPress RSS feed's image size in pixels?

Tags: css, wordpress, image, rss, size

Beyond the 'thumbnail' 'medium' and 'large' sizes? (and as seen applied in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9131274/4415757)

Image size doesn't seem to be customizable through mailchimp RSS-to-campaign editor, and when I tried to set a width and height inside the  tag in the RSS file, it didn't work; maybe a nested quotation marks issue?

Here is how I inserted my post featured image into the custom made RSS file:

```
<?php while(have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
  <item>
    <title><?php the_title_rss(); ?></title>
    <link><?php the_permalink_rss(); ?></link>
<?php if(get_the_post_thumbnail()): ?>
    <media:content url="<?php $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'medium'); echo $image[0]; ?>" medium="image" />
<?php endif; ?>
```

I tried to substitute 'medium' by 'thumbnail' and that seems to be he right parameter to manipulate, but when I tried to substitute it by 'width="600px" height="300px"' for example, I got the original image sizes instead.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution I found. It is not about defining the image size in pixels in the RSS file but more like creating a new image size category in wordpress and then calling that size in the RSS media tag.
According to the article http://havecamerawilltravel.com/photographer/wordpress-resize-thumbnails:

- I created an extra image size in wordpress, using the function add_image_size in my functions.php file. Example:

  ```
  <?php
  add_image_size( 'rss-thumb', 200, 150, true );
  add_image_size( 'search-thumb', 150, 150, true );
  add_filter( 'image_size_names_choose', 'my_custom_sizes' );
  function my_custom_sizes( $sizes ) {
      return array_merge( $sizes, array(
  'rss-thumb' => __( 'RSS Thumb' ),
  'search-thumb' => __( 'Search Thumb' ),
  ) );
  }?>
  ```
- Chosen the new image size in the RSS file, inside the  tag;

  ```
  <?php if(get_the_post_thumbnail()): ?>
      <media:content url="<?php $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'rss-thumb'); echo $image[0]; ?>" medium="image" />
  <?php endif; ?>
  ```
- Regenerated the thumbnails with the help of a plugin "Force Regenerate Thumbnails", so the existing images would be saved wih the newly created size-category also.

Comment: Thanks for this will try it out